# Export from select Statement to JSON in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.2. I know that for exporting data to JSON must use method like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE [conditions]
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('root')
```

but when I use this code in SQL Server Management Studio, an error occurred:

> Incorrect syntax near 'json'.

Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't have anything to do with Management Studio; the version of SSMS you're using is irrelevant. It has to do with the version of SQL Server you're running the code against, which is completely separate from the version of SSMS.

`FOR JSON` was introduced in SQL Server 2016. If you are not running 2016 or better (or Azure SQL Database), you'll need to upgrade, or use a different approach to get your data into JSON format.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I use FOR JSON in SQL server management 17.2 ?

Comment: There is no version of Management Studio that will let you use FOR JSON syntax against a server that doesn't support it. Management Studio isn't a database engine, it's just a GUI that lets you send commands to an engine. The engine that receives the command needs to support the syntax you send.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server-using-the-installation-wizard-setup?view=sql-server-2017